# Sequelize Many-to-Many Association -- "Include" query error saying there is no association

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have two models, "Users" and "Websites". Each user can have multiple websites and each website can have multiple users.

```
Users.associate = function(models) {
    Users.belongsToMany(models.Websites, {
      through: "UserWebsites",
      as: 'Websites',
      timestamps: false,
    });
  };
```

```
Websites.associate = function(models) {
        Websites.belongsToMany(models.Users, {
            through: "UserWebsites",
            as: 'Users',
            timestamps: false,
        });
    };
```

The query is:

```
let userId = req.params.id;

  db.Users.findOne({
    where: {
      id: userId
    },
    include: [{ model: db.Websites }]
  }).then(result => console.log(result));
```

I continue to get an error that is:

```
Unhandled rejection SequelizeEagerLoadingError: Websites is not associated to Users!
```

It's weird because sequelize also created a 'UserWebsites' table in MySQL showing that the association is there

Comment: you should add your model code but i suspect the error has something to do with your include... sure we can get to the bottom of it

Answer (score 0):

It should work. Here is a completed working demo using `"sequelize": "^5.21.3"`:

`index.ts`:

```js
import { sequelize } from '../../db';
import { Model, DataTypes } from 'sequelize';
import assert from 'assert';

class Users extends Model {}
Users.init(
  {
    id: {
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true,
      allowNull: false,
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    },
  },
  { sequelize, modelName: 'Users' },
);

class Websites extends Model {}
Websites.init(
  {
    url: DataTypes.STRING,
  },
  { sequelize, modelName: 'Websites' },
);

Users.belongsToMany(Websites, { through: 'UserWebsites', as: 'Websites', timestamps: false });
Websites.belongsToMany(Users, { through: 'UserWebsites', as: 'Users', timestamps: false });

(async function test() {
  try {
    await sequelize.sync({ force: true });
    const websitesOfUser1 = [{ url: 'twitter' }, { url: 'stackoverflow' }];
    const websitesOfUser2 = [{ url: 'github' }, { url: 'google' }];
    // seed
    await Users.bulkCreate(
      [
        { id: 1, Websites: websitesOfUser1 },
        { id: 2, Websites: websitesOfUser2 },
      ],
      { include: [{ model: Websites, as: 'Websites' }] },
    );

    // test
    const user = await Users.findOne({
      where: { id: 1 },
      include: [{ model: Websites, as: 'Websites' }],
    });
    assert.equal(user.Websites.length, websitesOfUser1.length, 'user 1 has two websites');
    const websitesDataValues = user.Websites.map((website) => website.dataValues);
    console.log('websitesDataValues: ', websitesDataValues);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } finally {
    await sequelize.close();
  }
})();
```

The execution results:

```sh
Executing (default): DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "UserWebsites" CASCADE;
Executing (default): DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "Websites" CASCADE;
Executing (default): DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "Users" CASCADE;
Executing (default): DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "Users" CASCADE;
Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "Users" ("id"   SERIAL , PRIMARY KEY ("id"));
Executing (default): SELECT i.relname AS name, ix.indisprimary AS primary, ix.indisunique AS unique, ix.indkey AS indkey, array_agg(a.attnum) as column_indexes, array_agg(a.attname) AS column_names, pg_get_indexdef(ix.indexrelid) AS definition FROM pg_class t, pg_class i, pg_index ix, pg_attribute a WHERE t.oid = ix.indrelid AND i.oid = ix.indexrelid AND a.attrelid = t.oid AND t.relkind = 'r' and t.relname = 'Users' GROUP BY i.relname, ix.indexrelid, ix.indisprimary, ix.indisunique, ix.indkey ORDER BY i.relname;
Executing (default): DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "Websites" CASCADE;
Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "Websites" ("id"   SERIAL , "url" VARCHAR(255), PRIMARY KEY ("id"));
Executing (default): SELECT i.relname AS name, ix.indisprimary AS primary, ix.indisunique AS unique, ix.indkey AS indkey, array_agg(a.attnum) as column_indexes, array_agg(a.attname) AS column_names, pg_get_indexdef(ix.indexrelid) AS definition FROM pg_class t, pg_class i, pg_index ix, pg_attribute a WHERE t.oid = ix.indrelid AND i.oid = ix.indexrelid AND a.attrelid = t.oid AND t.relkind = 'r' and t.relname = 'Websites' GROUP BY i.relname, ix.indexrelid, ix.indisprimary, ix.indisunique, ix.indkey ORDER BY i.relname;
Executing (default): DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "UserWebsites" CASCADE;
Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "UserWebsites" ("UserId" INTEGER  REFERENCES "Users" ("id") ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE, "WebsiteId" INTEGER  REFERENCES "Websites" ("id") ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE, PRIMARY KEY ("UserId","WebsiteId"));
Executing (default): SELECT i.relname AS name, ix.indisprimary AS primary, ix.indisunique AS unique, ix.indkey AS indkey, array_agg(a.attnum) as column_indexes, array_agg(a.attname) AS column_names, pg_get_indexdef(ix.indexrelid) AS definition FROM pg_class t, pg_class i, pg_index ix, pg_attribute a WHERE t.oid = ix.indrelid AND i.oid = ix.indexrelid AND a.attrelid = t.oid AND t.relkind = 'r' and t.relname = 'UserWebsites' GROUP BY i.relname, ix.indexrelid, ix.indisprimary, ix.indisunique, ix.indkey ORDER BY i.relname;
Executing (default): INSERT INTO "Users" ("id") VALUES (1),(2) RETURNING *;
Executing (default): INSERT INTO "Websites" ("id","url") VALUES (DEFAULT,'twitter'),(DEFAULT,'stackoverflow'),(DEFAULT,'github'),(DEFAULT,'google') RETURNING *;
Executing (default): INSERT INTO "UserWebsites" ("UserId","WebsiteId") VALUES (1,1),(1,2),(2,3),(2,4) RETURNING *;
Executing (default): SELECT "Users"."id", "Websites"."id" AS "Websites.id", "Websites"."url" AS "Websites.url", "Websites->UserWebsites"."UserId" AS "Websites.UserWebsites.UserId", "Websites->UserWebsites"."WebsiteId" AS "Websites.UserWebsites.WebsiteId" FROM "Users" AS "Users" LEFT OUTER JOIN ( "UserWebsites" AS "Websites->UserWebsites" INNER JOIN "Websites" AS "Websites" ON "Websites"."id" = "Websites->UserWebsites"."WebsiteId") ON "Users"."id" = "Websites->UserWebsites"."UserId" WHERE "Users"."id" = 1;
websitesDataValues:  [ { id: 1,
    url: 'twitter',
    UserWebsites:
     UserWebsites {
       dataValues: [Object],
       _previousDataValues: [Object],
       _changed: {},
       _modelOptions: [Object],
       _options: [Object],
       isNewRecord: false } },
  { id: 2,
    url: 'stackoverflow',
    UserWebsites:
     UserWebsites {
       dataValues: [Object],
       _previousDataValues: [Object],
       _changed: {},
       _modelOptions: [Object],
       _options: [Object],
       isNewRecord: false } } ]
```

Check the data records in the database:

```sh
node-sequelize-examples=# select * from "UserWebsites";
 UserId | WebsiteId
--------+-----------
      1 |         1
      1 |         2
      2 |         3
      2 |         4
(4 rows)

node-sequelize-examples=# select * from "Websites";
 id |      url
----+---------------
  1 | twitter
  2 | stackoverflow
  3 | github
  4 | google
(4 rows)

node-sequelize-examples=# select * from "Users";
 id
----
  1
  2
(2 rows)
```